# Moving files to other drive as previous OS stopped working

Tags: command-line, files, gui

I need some help with moving all the contents of my C: drive to a folder on another drive in the computer and I am trying to use Ubuntu now as my attempts with Zorin failed. Can I somehow just create a folder on the wanted drive and then move all files from C: drive to that folder either through the GUI or with the console?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity here. Is your “C:” on an external hard drive? Where is the destination? What is the file system on the destination? 

Comment: @matigo C: is also a internal drive, destination would be another windows marked drive and the file system is NTFS as windows standard i believe

Comment: Sure, you can do it...but you should have been able to do it with Zorin, too. It requires understanding of how to mount and unmount drives in the fliesystem, and understanding the differences between NTFS and ext4 filesystems. Once you learn those, the actual backup that you want to perform is quite easy. If you are looking for a step-by-step guide for somebody who doesn't have that understanding, you must say so clearly in your question and be willing to provide a lot of information.

Comment: This is a windows problem. Linux is not allowed to access a windows drive when it is dirty; the partition is flagged as dirty by windows and that needs to be solved in windows. Maybe it was hibernated.

Comment: This^^^ and the most typical reason for this since Windows 8 is the Fast Startup feature which is enabled by default. Disabled it in Windows then try again.